# Can I build a new Docker container within a Docker container?

Tags: docker, server, containers, sudo

I am trying to run a container on a server to which I don't have root permissions. I, therefore, can not build the container on the server. I do it locally and transfer the image file to the server. This takes a long time (> 6 hours).

I was wondering if I could build a container with capabilities to build another container within it.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Might be off-topic, but I'd insist on the root permisions or at least a sandbox server to do my attempts on. Of course a proper explanation must be given.

Comment: Giving access to the docker daemon but not root access on the host doesn't make much sense. If you can run containers, it's really easy to get root on the host. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface

Comment: I am actually running Singularity (which is Docker for supercomputing shared clusters)

Comment: You might take a look at 'docker in docker'. It comes with a bunch of caveats, but might suit your purpose https://hub.docker.com/_/docker

Comment: This might be what I am looking for, thanks! @HansKilian